# How do I create a function to search within a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

Write a function that would read a CSV file that looks like this, flowers.csv:

```
petunia,5.95
alyssum,3.95
begonia,5.95
sunflower,5.95
coelius,4.95
```

and look up the price of a flower and print out that price.

```
import csv

def problem3_7(csv_pricefile, flower):

  f = open(csv_pricefile) 

  for row in f:
    if row[0] == flower:
      print (row[1])    

  f.close()
```

I considered converting the CSV file into a dictionary so that by searching a flower it would give the price. I do believe there's a better way to do this by comparing the rows but I just can't seem to figure out how.

A row would consist of e.g `petunia, 5.95` and not just `petunia` which means I cannot compare the `rows == flower`. I tried using `row[0][0]` since it refers to only the name of the flower but it didn't really work for me.

And... I think I should be using some csv functions which I am currently not doing so.

Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: What's the size of your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing flower with the first character, not component. Try using:

```
    for row in f:
        cols = row.split(',')
        if cols[0].strip() == flower:
            print (cols[1].strip())
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer I was looking for. Just to clarify, what is the purpose of using the strip() function in this case? I tried running this function without the strip() function and it seems to be getting the right prices.

Comment: This is to remove occasional whitespaces (or other characters if you supply them as an argument), I inserted it habitually. If your dataset is well formatted, you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `csv.reader` and a dictionary comprehension to construct a mapping between flower name and price:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""petunia,5.95
alyssum,3.95
begonia,5.95
sunflower,5.95
coelius,4.95""")

# replace mystr with open(csv_pricefile)
with mystr as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    flower_prices = {name: float(price) for name, price in reader}

print(flower_prices)

{'alyssum': 3.95,
 'begonia': 5.95,
 'coelius': 4.95,
 'petunia': 5.95,
 'sunflower': 5.95}
```

Then extract the price of a specific flower via the dictionary, e.g. for petunia use `flower_prices['petunia']`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I haven't had the chance to test out StringIO in python but the answer I was looking for required the use of a simpler function without converting the data into a dictionary.

Would you say this method is more efficient as compared to the answer stated by Sianur below?

Comment: @PhangWeijun, You don't need to use `StringIO`. As per my comment, `replace mystr with open(csv_pricefile)`. I have included `StringIO" *only* for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Great! I've tried it and it works well. Would you say this is a better method as compared to doing row.split() and printing the separate columns? Is there an additional benefit to create a dictionary for this purpose?

Comment: A dictionary is more efficient for multiple lookups. A dictionary has O(1) complexity for each lookup. An iterative approach has O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
with open(csv_pricefile, 'r') as pricefile:
    df = pd.read_csv(pricefile, names=['flower', 'price'], index_col=0)
    data = df.to_dict(orient='index')
    # now you can get the price
    print(data[flower]['price'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd                                                              

src = "/path/to/data.csv"                                       
df = pd.read_csv(src, names=["flower","price"])                                  
print df                                                                         
#       flower  price                                                            
# 0    petunia   5.95                                                            
# 1    alyssum   3.95                                                            
# 2    begonia   5.95                                                            
# 3  sunflower   5.95                                                            
# 4    coelius   4.95                                                            

# Retrieve the row with a flower called petunia                                  
row_result = df.loc[df['flower'] == 'petunia']                                   
print row_result                                                                 
#     flower  price                                                              
# 0  petunia   5.95                                                              

# Retrieve the price of the first row                                            
if row_result:                                                                   
    price = row_result.iloc[0]['price']                                          
    print price                                                                  
    # 5.95                                                                       
else:                                                                            
    print "Not Found"
```